# Not able to load, on karma testing, a scss file, imported in a component's scss file, in an angular js app

Tags: angular, sass, karma-jasmine

**Problem**
On running the karma test for login component, I get the error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'variables.scss' in '<project>\src\app\components\auth\login'
```

---

**Project**

1. I am making a unit test case for a component `login`:

   ```
   //assuming all the imports here
   describe('LoginComponent', () => {
   let component: LoginComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, MaterialModule,AppRoutingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
       declarations: [ LoginComponent, LayoutComponent ],
       providers: [{
         provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'
       }]
     })
     .compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
   });
   ```
2. This is the login component's scss file

   ```
   @import 'variables.scss';
   ```
3. This is my project structure

   `project folder
   |
   |_e2e
   |_node_modules
   |_src
     |_app
     | |_components
     | |     |_auth
     | |         |_login
     | |             |_login.component.html
     | |             |_login.component.scss
     | |             |_login.component.spec.ts
     | |             |_login.component.ts
     | |             |_login.model.ts
     | |
     | |_app.component.ts
     | |_app.module.ts
     | ...
     |
     |_variables.scss
     |_test.ts
     |_karma.conf.js
     ...`

---

**Solution tried** : using `karma-scss-prepocessor`

This is my karma.conf.js file

```
  module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
      plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
        require('karma-scss-preprocessor')
      ],
      client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      },
      coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
        reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
      },
      reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
      port: 9876,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      autoWatch: true,
      browsers: ['Chrome'],
      singleRun: false,
      files: [
        {pattern: 'app/**/**/**/*.scss', included: false},
        {pattern: 'app/**/**/*.scss', included: false},
        'variables.scss'
      ],
      preprocessors: {
        'variables.scss': ['scss']
      }
    });
  };
```

So basically i am not able to load the scss file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose that there is nothing to do with Karma. Try to change the import to reflect the folder structure, because your path is about _variables.scss that in the same folder with your component, meanwhile it's not there

Comment: Also, you have a `styles.scss` in your `src` folder. You better import your variables in there, thus they are available through the project since `styles.scss` are not encapsulated

Answer (score 2):

check your angular.json file
if you use variables in styles.scss there should be something like this

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "projects/your-project-name/src/app/styles"
              ]
            },
```

then check if section "Test" have same option stylePreprocessorOptions